# Best practice: For ensuring a good print with dual extruder machine

Tags: filament, extruder, qidi-x-pro

I own a Qidi X-Pro that uses a dual extruder.  I just spent the last 45 minutes trying to print, over and over, a simple model I had printed before.  I'm using ABS with a glue stick.  The ABS is fed through the left extruder while PLA is fed through the right.  I had previously printed a different model and had finished it.  I was now attempting to print a different model with the left extruder and ABS.

The ABS print would almost fail immediately with the filament catching on other parts of the model.  Then, I realized that a small piece of PLA was still exposed on the right extruder and it would catch the model as I was printing with ABS.

Is there a recommended way to ensure that this does not happen in the future?  What nozzle 'clean up', if any, should I perform after printing?

Comment: Can you provide a photo? Are the two nozzles the exact same height from the bed?

Comment: It is unusual to mix ABS and PLA in one print. One drawback is the ABS prints much hotter, so is more likely to melt into the PLA in an unpredictable way. Out of curiosity do you have a compelling reason to use the two together, or is it just the materials on hand?

Comment: bed temps are going to make for an interesting combination too. ABS gets close to 100 °C and PLA can handle room temperature in the right conditions.

Comment: Trish's question is a good one. You have to ensure your nozzles are properly calibrated for clearance.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I created by my wording.  I've updated the text to reflect that I was not using both extruders when the problem occurred.  And, yes, the bed is level.  I've leveled it with leveling squares.